# Format a flat array of objects to a nested array of object based on property level

Tags: javascript, arrays

This is the data coming in.

```
let list = [
    {
        name: "h1",
        level: 1,
        children: []
    },
    {
        name: "h2",
        level: 2,
        children: []
    },
    {
        name: "h3",
        level: 3,
        children: []
    },
    {
        name: "paragraph",
        level: 1,
        children: []
    },
    {
        name: "bold",
        level: 2,
        children: []
    },
    {
        name: "italic",
        level: 2,
        children: []
    },
    {
        name: "paragraph",
        level: 1,
        children: []
    }

]
```

The result the results like this

```
 [
 {
  "name": "h1",
  "level": 1,
  "children": [
   {
    "name": "h2",
    "level": 2,
    "children": [{
         "name": "h3",
         "level": 3,
        "children": []
   }]
    }   
  ]
 },
 {
  "name": "paragraph",
  "level": 1,
  "children": [
   {
    "name": "bold",
    "level": 2,
    "children": []
   },
   {
    "name": "italic",
    "level": 2,
    "children": []
   }
  ]
 },
 {
  "name": "paragraph",
  "level": 1,
  "children": []
 }
]
```

This is my attempt. The issue is I am only carrying the finalist and the current value between iterations. When the level is greater I add it to the last item children value. That works for the first tier. But how would i tell it to check its children as well and bubble down the whole object to make the correct insert.

It should only add to the children if its greater if its equal to the child add it as a sibling instead. I seem to only be able to do either or. I have code where i nest children but then i can't do siblings. I am going in circles.

```
const initialValue = [];
const output = list.reduce((acc,curr, index,arr)=>{
        console.log(index,"start========:",acc, "||", curr)

        if(index === 0){
            console.log(index, "push first into array")
            return acc.concat([curr])
        }

        console.log(index,"compare level?",acc[acc.length - 1].level,  curr.level)

        if(acc[acc.length - 1].level <  curr.level){
            console.log(index, acc[acc.length - 1].children, "push bold into paragraph")
            acc[acc.length - 1].children.push(curr);
            console.log(index, "check result?", acc)
            return acc
        } else {
            return acc.concat([curr])
        }
        return acc;

}, initialValue

);

console.log("output:",JSON.stringify(output,null, 1))
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that an element whose `.level` has a value of `i` cannot be succeeded by an element whose `level`'s value is greater than `i + 1`:

(this is written as explicitly as possible for ease of explanation; a terser version can be found in the snippet below)

```js
function makeTreesFromObjects(objects) {
    const stack = [{ children: [] }];

    for (const originalObject of objects) {
        let object = structuredClone(originalObject);

        if (object.level < stack.length - 1) {

            stack.splice(object.level, Infinity, object);
            stack.at(-2).children.push(object);

        } else if (object.level > stack.length - 1) {

            stack.at(-1).children.push(object);
            stack.push(object);

        } else if (object.level === stack.length - 1) {

            stack.at(-2).children.push(object);
            stack.splice(-1, 1, object);

        }
    }

    return stack[0].children;
}
```

### Explanation

First, create a stack which consists of a "root" element; its children will be the new list we want:

```js
const stack = [{ children: [] }];
```

Then, iterate over the list of given elements and clone them as we go:

```js
for (const originalObject of objects) {
    let object = structuredClone(originalObject);

    // ...
}
```

If `object` (current element) is shallower than the topmost one of the stack, pop everything after `object`'s level and push it to the stack. We also push it to the second topmost one's `.children` as it has now become `object`'s parent:

```js
if (object.level < stack.length - 1) {
    stack.splice(object.level, Infinity, object);
    stack.at(-2).children.push(object);
}

/*

Stack:

┌─────────┬─────────┬─────────┬─────────┐
│    0    │    1    │    a    │    b    │
├─────────┼─────────┼─────────┼─────────┤
│ [1]     │ [a]     │ [b]     │ []      │

Current element:
                    ┌─────────┐
                    │    c    │
                    └─────────┘

After:
┌─────────┬─────────┬─────────┐
│    0    │    1    │    c    │
├─────────┼─────────┼─────────┤
│ [1]     │ [a, c]  │ []      │

*/
```

If `object` is deeper, push it to the stack and topmost element's `.children`:

```js
if (object.level > stack.length - 1) {
    stack.at(-1).children.push(object);
    stack.push(object);
}

/*

Stack:

┌─────────┬─────────┬─────────┬─────────┐
│    0    │    1    │    a    │    b    │
├─────────┼─────────┼─────────┼─────────┤
│ [1]     │ [a]     │ [b]     │ []      │

Current element:
                                        ┌─────────┐
                                        │    c    │
                                        └─────────┘

After:
┌─────────┬─────────┬─────────┬─────────┬─────────┐
│    0    │    1    │    a    │    b    │    c    │
├─────────┼─────────┼─────────┼─────────┼─────────┤
│ [1]     │ [a]     │ [b]     │ [c]     │ []      │

*/
```

If `object`'s level is the same as topmost element's, make `object` the new topmost and push it to second topmost's `.children`:

```js
if (object.level === stack.length - 1) {
    stack.at(-2).children.push(object);
    stack.splice(-1, 1, object);
}

/*

Stack:

┌─────────┬─────────┬─────────┬─────────┐
│    0    │    1    │    a    │    b    │
├─────────┼─────────┼─────────┼─────────┤
│ [1]     │ [a]     │ [b]     │ []      │

Current element:
                              ┌─────────┐
                              │    c    │
                              └─────────┘

After:
┌─────────┬─────────┬─────────┬─────────┐
│    0    │    1    │    a    │    c    │
├─────────┼─────────┼─────────┼─────────┤
│ [1]     │ [a]     │ [b, c]  │ []      │

*/
```

Finally, return the bottommost (or "root")'s children; that's the list we want.

```js
return stack[0].children;
```

Try it:

```js
function makeTreesFromObjects(objects) {
    const stack = [{ children: [] }];

    for (const originalObject of objects) {
        let object = structuredClone(originalObject);

        stack.splice(object.level, Infinity, object);
        stack.at(-2).children.push(object);
    }

    return stack[0].children;
}

const list = [
    {
        name: 'h1',
        level: 1,
        children: []
    },
    {
        name: 'h2',
        level: 2,
        children: []
    },
    {
        name: 'h3',
        level: 3,
        children: []
    },
    {
        name: 'paragraph',
        level: 1,
        children: []
    },
    {
        name: 'bold',
        level: 2,
        children: []
    },
    {
        name: 'italic',
        level: 2,
        children: []
    },
    {
        name: 'span',
        level: 3,
        children: []
    },
    {
        name: 'a',
        level: 2,
        children: []
    },
    {
        name: 'bold',
        level: 3,
        children: []
    },
    {
        name: 'paragraph',
        level: 1,
        children: []
    }
];

console.log(JSON.stringify(makeTreesFromObjects(list), null, 2));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Comment: I would personally change the solution to `stack.splice(object.level, Infinity, object.children)`, followed by `stack.at(-2).push(object)`, with `[[]]` as the starting stack and `stack[0]` as the return value. There is no reason to store the entire object in the stack when you only need access to the children. This is a great answer nonetheless.